# Issue with CSS Grid and @media query

Tags: css, media-queries, css-grid

This is my CSS code

```
 article {
    background-color: lightblue;
    border: solid;
    margin: 0;
    display: grid;
    height: 100%;  }
 footer{
    background-color: darkslategray;
    display: grid;
    padding: 1.5rem;  } 
    @media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    article {
        display: grid;
        grid-template-areas: 'sc1' 
                             'as1'
                             'sc2' 
                             'as2'
                             'sc3' 
                             '..';}
    footer {
        display: grid;
        grid-template-areas: 'nv1'
                             'nv2';}}
  @media screen and (min-width: 600px) {
    article {
        display: grid;
        grid-template-areas: 'sc1' 'as1'
                             'sc2' 'as2'
                             'sc3' '..';}
    footer {
        display: grid;
        grid-template-areas: 'nv1'
                             'nv2';}  }
  @media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
    article {
        display: grid;
        grid-template-areas: 'sc1' 'as1'
                             'sc2' 'as2'
                             'sc3' '..';
    }
    footer {
        display: grid;
        grid-template-areas: 'nv1'
                             'nv2';}  }
```

On the browser the output is showing first media query result no matter what the screen size is..

Where am I wrong??

Syntax of code seems to me right. I want to change grid-template-area according to screen size

Answer (score 0):

Divide the row into two columns using `grid-template-columns`. As a side note, you don't need to repeat `display : grid` from media query to media query unless you have changed it before, you should avoid mixing `min-width` and `max-width`. Just take the `max-width : 600px` out of the media query and you will be fine for small screens.

```
article {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
    grid-template-areas: 'sc1' 'as1'
                         'sc2' 'as2'
                         'sc3' '..';
}
```